# Different indent styles of Ocaml in Emacs

Tags: emacs, ocaml, indentation

I am writing Ocaml code under Emacs. Currently, the indent style is like the following, that is, the code where a variable is defined by `let` is a little bit on the left of `let`.

```
let v = 5 in
  Printf.printf "v= %d\n" v
```

I also see some files written by others, when I open them, the indent style is that the code  is in the same column as `let`:

```
let v = 5 in
Printf.printf "v= %d\n" v
```

I think the second style looks better, does anyone know where I could setup Emacs so that my Emacs takes the second style?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look to the 'tuareg-in-indent' setting, that sets how much ident should be done (0 to disable) - you can customize it with M-x customize-variable...

P.S. you can also look to 'tuareg-let-always-indent' variable...

Comment: thanks for your comment. I have added `(setq tuareg-let-always-indent nil)` to my `.emacs`, when I check `M-x customize-variable`, it shows `off (nil)` as expected. but still it follows the first style in my initial post... I don't know what is wrong...

Comment: I edited answer right after I sent it, pointing that tuareg-in-indent should be right answer - at least, it works in my installation...

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [ocp-indent](https://github.com/OCamlPro/ocp-indent) which indents by default using the second style.